# Firebase Auth fails to catch errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase Auth to authenticate users following the Google documentation.

I am using the following versions:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/password-auth

I am using the following example from the documentation.

```
try {
  final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
     emailAddress, password
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

When I enter an invalid password ... I get a record on the consold indicating the error but it is not caught in the application.

```
[firebase_auth/invalid-login-credentials] Error
```

I can assess the credentials which are null when it fails and a valid User when successfully logged in but have no access to the cause of the error/exception outside what is printed on the console.

I get similar results deploying to Chrome or a Physical device.

I would like to be able to catch the exception to present the error back to the user in the application.

Comment: Firebase projects created since September 15 have [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) enabled by default, which means the APIs respond differently to make it harder for attackers to get the email addresses for your user. See the question and docs I linked for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, this is good info and will follow the guidance provide. I think there is something else going on here in that I don't get ANY exceptions caught and the details responses do show up on the console.  None the less, I have refactored the code to test the response for null and provide a generic message to the user.  I also provided my own "rules" on the application side to enforce more secure passwords.

Comment: Hmm... tricky. The code in your question still tries to handle error codes the the API no longer returns though as far as I can see though.

Comment: I get `invalid-login-credentials` here: https://zapp.run/edit/email-enumeration-protection-z776066c7770?file=lib/main.dart&entry=lib/main.dart